# Rails - Rspec/Capybara reporting fail unless sleep added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a page where a logged in user can set a favourite item by submitting an ajax request which calls the following controller method:

```
def create
    item = Item.find(params[:id])
    if params[:commit] == 'save'
        item.unhide!(current_user) if item.is_hidden_by?(current_user)
        item.save_as_favourite_for!(current_user)
    else
        item.remove_as_favourite!(current_user) if item.is_favourite_of?(current_user)
        item.hide_for!(current_user)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_back_or items_path }
     format.js {render "create", locals: {item: item, index: params[:index].to_i || nil, page:params[:page]} }
    end
end
```

This all works as expected, but I have a request spec which is defined to test the front end functionality:

```
describe "saving items", js: true do

    let!(:current_user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "user@example.com", active: true)}

    let!(:favourite_item) {FactoryGirl.create(:item)}
    before { sign_in current_user }

    describe "when saving a item" do

        it "should save the user against the item" do

            expect do

                click_button "save"
                # sleep(0.02)

            end.to change(favourite_item.savers, :count).by(1)

        end
    end
end
```

Notice the commented out sleep(0.02) statement. If this statement is commented out, the test (almost) always fails, however if I include the call, and immediately end the console interrupt, then the test passes every time. (any more time delay and it fails).

Is there a better way to write this test without the workaround and why might it be failing without the delay?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a wait time using the dsl.

```
using_wait_time 3 do
  expect do
    click_button "save"
  end.to change(favourite_item.savers, :count).by(1)
end
```

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara.using_wait_time

The default wait time is 2 seconds for JS tests if you use an Rspec matcher, which you are not for this test.

It'll probably also pass if you remove `js: true` unless you really need the js driver for the test.

Comment: How does that differ from adding sleep into the block? Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work in this case anyway. I will review my tests to check, as I may have been liberal with the js: true, but I am sure that in most cases js is in play.